# Filtro dinamico Ajax, jquery - Me podran colaborar con la creación de la tabla a partir del objeto

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Necesito armar la tabla a partir de la variable respuesta, dentro de la misma se encuentran los valores seleccionados.
En principio tengo mi codigo JS, con la funcion filtro, pero cuando llego a armar la tabla no se como. Soy nuevo en programacion y necesito si me ayudan.

````javascript
function filtro(){
  var valor = document.getElementById('filtrobusc').value; 
// valor que deseo filtrar
  var tabla = $("#tabla");
// guardo en la variable tabla, todos los registros de la tabla
  $.ajax(
    {
      url:"/sitios/filtrar?valor=" + valor, 
// hago un query qu ebusca el valor  que entro en el imput
      type:"GET",
      data:"",
      error: function(err){
        console.log("El error es ", err);
      },
      success: function(respuesta){ 

      tabla.remove();
 
      }    }
  )
};

```pug
 form
          table#tabla(name= "tabla")
              thead
                tr
                  th
                    input(type="checkbox")
                  th
                    p Codigo
                  th
                    p Nombre
                  th
                    p Localidad  
                  th  
                    p Latitud
                  th
                    p Longitud
                  th
                    p Altura
                  th
                    p Radio
Necersito hacer un filto dinamico con ajax, peor no consigo
````

Comment: Por favor, lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Pulsa en [edit] y describe el problema en cuestión ("no sé hacerlo" no es argumento suficiente). Ten siempre presente que [**aquí no hacemos tareas**](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4320) ni damos tutoriales.

Comment: Buenas tardes, No estoy buscando que hagan ninguna tarea ni que me den un tutorial,  simplemenmte pregunte. Si no te gusta no mires, ni respondas.  Ten siempre presente que deberias ser mas cordial. ok?

Comment: Por eso es bueno leer el [código de conducta](/conduct) :) Las primeras preguntas de los usuarios entran a la [cola](/review) de _Primeras preguntas_. No es la cuestión de gustos o no, es simple moderación que todos hacemos en el sitio (incluso vos también podés hacerlo). Pulsá en [edit] y describí el problema _específico_ que estás teniendo.

Comment: Ok, ahi va bastante mejor,  creo que es bueno mostrar en que se esta equivocando alquien que recien entra, simplemente con un poco de empatia.Gracias.